# How to load variables from ansible role

Tags: ansible, vsphere

I have a task to create vmware which is using variables from a role. I'm using a bash script to generate vars file automatically and then the next task will use vars for deploying vm. The problem is that I have to set `vars_files` path in role and also define it in my playbook. So it will run or I'll got the error message something like **"variable_name is undefined.."**. I've tried to using pause/wait_for module to validate the task generate vars from script, but, it won't work.

```
$ tree roles/
roles/
└── vm
    ├── tasks
    │   └── main.yml
    └── vars
        ├── vars_vm.yml
```

Here's my playbook from the role folder:

- vmware/vars/vars_vm.yml => The file `vars_vm` is generate from task bash script

```
vars_vm:
   - vm_name: VM_001
```

- vm-ware/task/main.yml

```
- name: Generate vars
  script: generate_vm_vars.sh 2
  register: result

- include_vars: "{{ vars_file }}"
  name: foo

- debug:
  var: foo

- name: Modify Tier0
  vmware_deploy_ovf:
    hostname: "********"
    username: "admin"
    password: "********"
    validate_certs: False
    state: present
    name: "{{ item.vm_name }}"
    ovf: "{{ path }}"
    wait_for_ip_address: true
    power_on: no
    datastore: "{{ store }}"
    network: "{{ network }}"
  with_items: "{{ vars_vm }}"
```

Here's the main file of role

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - {"role": vm, "vars_file": "path/../vars/vars_vm.yml"}
```

My expected result:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - vm
```

Is there any other way I could run the role without add "vars_file"?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your variables should be in _default/main.yml_; [_default variables for the role. These variables have the lowest priority of any variables available, and can be easily overridden by any other variable, including inventory variables._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure)

Comment: Actually, I've already tried to put it in default/main.yml. However, I got the same message "vars... is undefined".

Comment: variables in `default/main.yml` and `vars/main.yml` in your role are automatically available. You don't need to include anything (besides simply using the role in your playbook).